# Build error - The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nuget-package

I have just opened a project that was working fine the other day. No changes were made to the code but now when I open it I get errors

> The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?

The only thing that has changed is VS has upgraded to 16.5

How do I fix this? The packages are all there and Nuget reports everything is installed. I have tried uninstalling the packages and reinstalling them but still get the error.

This is my .csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```